# Frontispiece for thesis UK

Tags: titles, loops, thesis

I am writing the title page of my thesis, but the frontispizo package described elsewhere on this website doesn't really suit my needs. I am sure the frontispiece I require below can be easily implemented, if I knew how, see below for layout, (or http://www.lboro.ac.uk/students/welcome/research/codes-of-practice/appendices/#app5 about 3/4 of the way down the page).

Title
(Skip line(s))
by
(Skip line(s))
Author
(Skip line(s))
Doctoral Thesis
(Skip line(s))
Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements
for the award of Doctor of Philosophy of Loughborough University
(Skip line(s))
Date
(Skip line(s))
copyright by author, date

All of the above should be centered. Any help would be appreciated. Rube

Thanks Harish, that gives me exactly what I want and complete control over the layout, unlike using a macro which one may not necessarily understand. Thanks again. Rube

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this page a separate document or part a single thesis document.  If the latter, please tell us how that thesis document is set-up, in particular which class you are using.  In either case please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, no, with the `frontespizio` package you can't get that kind of frontispiece.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by yourself using `titlepage`. Adjust the values in all `\vspace{<value>}` as suited by yourself.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\huge This is the title of your thesis This is the title of your thesis
    This is the title of your thesis}

    \vspace{1cm}
    by

    \vspace{1cm}
    {\large The author}

    \vspace{1cm}
    {\large Doctoral thesis}

    \vspace{1cm}
    Submitted  in partial fulfillment of the requirements

    for the award of

    Doctor of Philosophy of Loughborough University

    \vspace{1cm}
    \date{29.01.2015}

    \vfill
    \copyright by the author, \date{29.01.2015}
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```